# Libgdx Scrollpane scroll per fling to next column

Tags: libgdx, scrollpane

I have table with 5 columns, that inserted in ScrollPane, and i want to that ScrollPane will scroll only to the next element, even if velocity was too high.
Is anyone faced with this issue?

Comment: There are various set options within the Scrollpane class, for example have you tried `setFlickScroll(boolean flickScroll)` - honestly, I've never used the Scrollpane class, I'm just trying to find out what you have tried?

Comment: Thank you for response. But i have solved my problem just setting fling too small.